# upload android application to android market

Tags: android, google-play

I have developed an Android game application and I want to upload it to the Android Market.
What is the procedure for this?

Answer (score 9):

First, read the manual, it's not that complicated. But basically:

- Make an android market account (It will cost you 25 dollars i think)
- Go to the market.
- Make sure your apk is signed as described in the manual.
- Fill in the details of your apk, upload it, etc
- press Publish
- ....
- profit!

Comment: :-P (Monetary) Profit is only when your app is paid

Comment: (Or when someone pays you to publish it. Or when there are ads.) But it was a bit tongue-in-cheek

Answer (score 3):

Have you read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html ?

Answer (score 0):

Sign up for a developer account: https://play.google.com/apps/publish/signup

Distribute your app: http://developer.android.com/distribute/index.html